# Angularjs focus on input text after 3 characters

Tags: angularjs

I am using Ionic Angularjs and want, after typing 3 characters into a input type text, to set the focus on the next input .

Can I use `limitTo` filter combining with another angularjs feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can use AngularJS directives, combined with HTML5's input `maxlength` attribute:

**The directive**

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .directive('focusAfter', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        elemToFocus: '@'
      },
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        var elementToFocus = document.getElementById(scope.elemToFocus);
        elem.on('keyup', function() {
          if(elem.val().length === 3) {
            window.setTimeout(function() {
              elementToFocus.focus();
            });

          }
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

**View**

```
<input type="text" maxlength="3" id="input1" focus-after elem-to-focus="input2">
<input type="text" maxlength="3" id="input2" focus-after elem-to-focus="input3">
<input type="text" maxlength="3" id="input3" focus-after elem-to-focus="input1">
```

Here's a plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/QvS0dwUNW3oAhHID1VRX?p=info